# Angular - Access injector in catch statement for main.ts?

Tags: angular

Our `main.ts` is not that different from most ones:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import './component-map';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err)); <-------- Need access to injector tree here
```

Would like to access the injector tree in the catch block, but just have access to the JS error. IS there a way? Let's say I need `ErrorHandlerService` to send errors to third party service.

Comment: I think you can solve your problem without using injector here.
For example you can create global bus:
```export const globalErrorBus = {
    emitError();
    subscribe(); 
}```

So you can send messages through it from `main.ts` and subscribe to it directly in your `ErrorHandlerService`

Comment: Like this:
`main.ts`:
`.catch((err) => globalErrorBus.emitError(err));`
`handler.service.ts`:
`globalErrorBus.subscribe(err => /** do smth with your error **/)`

Comment: If you do want to use injector this method returns module object where you can access injector https://angular.io/api/core/PlatformRef#bootstrapModule